# Execute Code Upon Admin Section Save

Tags: admin, magento-1.6

**Situation:** I have some custom code that I would like to have evaluated when someone clicks "Save Category" within the "Manage Categories" section of the Admin panel. I am thinking that this can be accomplished via an Observer, but I'm not certain.

**Question:** Is an Observer the correct way of accomplishing this task? If so, how would I identify the correct Observer to use in this situation?

Thank you for any insight!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for ProxiBlue for a great explanation. And now to precisely answer the question:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_category_save
```

is the event to be observed.

**To know what is the event to observe:**

i use the following function in my observer to find the action to be observed. In

> Model/Observer.php

```
public function hookToControllerActionPostDispatch($observer) {
    Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());
}
```

In

> etc/config.xml

```
<controller_action_postdispatch>
    <observers>
        <controller_action_after>
            <class>Royal_ObserveEvents_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>hookToControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
        </controller_action_after>
    </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch>
```

this logs the controller and action called during the event, prefix either `controller_action_postdispatch` or `controller_action_predispatch` to the action logged according to; when you're going to trigger your event observer.

Comment: OP asked 'how' not 'which' ;)

Comment: I think that's what I tried to explain in the second part of my answer ;). If it's wrong, pls notify me so that I'll remove it.

Comment: Not at all, just noting, just ignore me :)

Comment: cool! jus wanna make sure :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I appreciate how you gave code examples for each part of the process.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, yes, an observer would be the best way, but it can also be done via rewrites. I personally always try to achieve my customization via observers, as it allows for a much higher module compatibility.

How to obtain the correct event: Stay away from the multitude of 'event lists' available, all over the place. They are generally dated, and in most cases miss out on dynamic generated events

I find the best way is to do a quick edit in /app/mage.php in the dispatchEvent method. Basically just send the list of events generated to the system.log.

So I place a mage::log($name); as the first line in the method, and then I tail var/log/system.log. I then perform the action I am looking to extend, and view the events fired. Some zen-logic (well just common sense ;) ) and you will see the events you would potentially use.

**(remember to remove this edit immediately after you locate the event you are interested in)**

Now, for what event...this really depends on what you need to do.

Are you interested in some field data that gets posted (so some custom field you added), then the controller post/pre events would be best, as it gives you access to the request object, thus allowing you to get the posted data. In some cases teh actual action you are extending can fire its own events, which woudl be better than pre/post events.

If you do not need to collect posted data, then you'd most likely need the category model save (or before/after save) events.

These are just two potential examples. It really depends on what you need to do in your custom code.

Try not to use the generic events, as they can really slow your system down, as they will run on every action (thus stay away from the generic ...model_save events, and target the model's event that gets fired)

see for example the code in Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

```
protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->isObjectNew(true);
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());   <<<<< TARGET THIS EVENT, NOT THE GENERIC ONE!!
        return $this;
    }
```

also, in config.xml, try and target the correct area, when you place your observer directives. Don't just put them all in the global tag. If your event is only an admin event, then place the observer event in the adminhtml tag area, and the same goes for frontend. see my short blog post avout it here : http://www.dhmedia.com.au/article/magento-improve-performance-selective-events

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful post! You have provided me with great direction on accomplishing my task. I'm awarding @Shathish the answer due to his detailed response. I recognize that I did ask how, and not which ( which you pointed out below ), but he provided a very clear way of accomplishing the task. I tried to select you both as the correct answer, but I couldn't. Thank you again!